# How can I read an XML and also preserve the sequence of tags so that the meaning is intact?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

I have been using `lxml` and `objectify` to read XMLs thus far:

1. I created custom classes with the same name as tags
2. I used **for** loops to read the objectified xml-tags and mapped them into my custom classes

The above technique worked as I didn't need to preserve the sequence of tags.

However, now, I have a new challenge.

Check the following XML file:

```
<member>
    <detaileddescription>
        Hello
        <formula id="39">my</formula>
        name
        <formula id="102">is</formula>
        Buddy.
        <formula id="103">I</formula>
        am a
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
            superhero
            <formula id="104">.</formula>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                At least,
                <formula id="105">I think</formula>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        so...:)
        <simplesect kind="see">
            What
            <ref refid="ref_id" kindref="ref_kindref">do you</ref>
            <bold>think</bold> ?
        </simplesect>
        Let me know.
    </detaileddescription>
 </member>
```

My task is to read it and also preserve its meaning between the tags.

I have experimented a lot. However, I haven't been able to succeed in finding a way.

```
from lxml import etree, objectify


def to_list(root):
    my_list = []
    for item in root.iter():
        if item.text is not None:
            text = item.text.strip()
            if text is not "":
                my_list.append("text####" + text)

        if item.tail is not None:
            tail = item.tail.strip()
            if tail is not "":
                my_list.append("tail####" + tail)
    return my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_file = r"xml.xml"

    class_dom = etree.parse(in_file)
    class_xml_bin = etree.tostring(class_dom, pretty_print=False, encoding="ascii")
    class_xml_text = class_xml_bin.decode()
    root = objectify.fromstring(class_xml_text)

    my_list = to_list(root.detaileddescription)

    for item in my_list:
        print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
text####Hello
text####my
tail####name
text####is
tail####Buddy.
text####I
tail####am a
tail####so...:)
text####superhero
text####.
text####At least,
text####I think
text####What
tail####Let me know.
text####do you
text####think
tail####?
```

Here you can see the output doesn't fully maintain the exact sequence. For instance, `so...:)` is out of place.

Another major problem with this solution is, **it doesn't keep the XML content as classes.** Rather the output is directly text output.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Note:** I must not use **xpath**.

Comment: This issue might occur because you add the text and tail into the list sequentially inside the same for loop before traversing deeper in the xml's structure.

Comment: if need is exact sequence - then how about ` soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'lxml')
[each.text.strip().replace("\n","") for each in soup] ` and it will create output list as ['Hello        my        name        is        Buddy.        I        am a                    superhero            .                At least,                I think        so...:)                    What            do youthink ?                Let me know.']

Comment: @simpleApp, I need to be able to select a particular tag also, not only `root`.

Comment: To get all the text in the correct order, you can use `itertext()`. https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext